# How to differentiate translation of a verb and a noun in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to localize a Django application, but I could not find any way to differentiate translation of a verb and a noun.

Let's say I have a word "order" that is used as a verb in one case, and a noun in another. In the .po file it appears as:

```
#: .\core\order.py:747
msgid "Order"
msgstr ""
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contextual markers should do exactly what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers

Comment: Was looking for {% trans "May" context "month name" %}, which unfortunately is not supported by Django 1.3.

Comment: You are right, was not aware that you are on 1.3. But maybe it is worth upgrading ...